# Do quotation marks used to name something go inside or outside commas in Chicago style?

Tags: punctuation, chicago-manual-of-style

I am using quotation marks like this:

> Joshua Abraham Norton, who liked to call himself "Emperor", dressed in elaborate clothing.

> The strange fish, which scientists call a "coelacanth", lived in deep underwater caves.

My question is, does the quotation mark around these words go inside (as I've shown above), or is it correct to put them outside punctuation, as below, which my proofreader wants to change:

> Joshua Abraham Norton, who liked to call himself "Emperor," dressed in elaborate clothing.

> The strange fish, which scientists call a "coelacanth," lived in deep underwater caves.

I checked the Chicago Manual of Style, but can't see this usage of quotation marks used in their examples. Which way is correct?

Comment: The latter looks really weird to me. But your proofreader might be a better representative of your audience than me.
You could also consider replacing quotes with using italics: "Joshua Abraham Norton, who liked to call himself *Emperor*, dressed in elaborate clothing."

Comment: Punctuation inside quotes is the American way. This question looks like a duplicate of [Punctuation-Quote or Quote-Punctuation?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/q/3362/34330)

Comment: If the part in quotes is a complete sentence, or it's a literal quote of *spoken* dialog, the 1st word of the phrase will be capitalized and the punctuation will be *inside* the quotes (a comma or a period). In your examples, the word inside the quotes is not a phrase or spoken dialog so any punctuation is incidental (the punctuation stays outside with the sentence).

Comment: @laurel I agree and started a vote. Village, remember close votes are not a personal thing. It's just good site maintenance so people can find the answers they need. If you disagree, tell us why your question is different than the linked one.

Comment: The other question isn't using quotes the same way.